# TYPO3 typoscript mySql Select, get the same db field 2 times

Tags: mysql, typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.1.x

newbie to TYPO3 but learning.

I have this code

```
lib.GetSubCat = CONTENT
lib.GetSubCat {
    wrap = <div class="p_filter"><div class="p_filter_container"><a class="p_cat_filter button" href="#" title="Under Emne" data-filter="article.portfolio"><span>Under Emne</span></a><ul class="p_filter"><li class="current"><a href="#" title="Under Emne" data-filter="article.portfolio">Under Emne</a></li>|</ul></div><div class="cl"></div></div>
    table = tx_tbpdrills_domain_model_drillsubcategory
    select {
        pidInList = 18
        where = NOT deleted AND NOT hidden      
        orderBy = subcategorytitle ASC
    }
    renderObj = COA_INT
    renderObj {     
        10 = TEXT       
        10.field = subcatshort
        10.wrap = <li><a href="#" title="###" data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='###']">|</a></li>
    }   
}
```

Working fine, now i want to add an extra field from my DB, and i have this code, and its also working.

```
......
    table = tx_tbpdrills_domain_model_drillsubcategory
    select {
        pidInList = 18
        where = NOT deleted AND NOT hidden      
        orderBy = subcategorytitle ASC
    }
    renderObj = COA_INT
    renderObj {     
        10 = TEXT       
        10.field = subcatshort
        10.wrap = <li><a href="#" title="###" data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='|']">
        20 = TEXT
        20.field = subcategorytitle
        20.wrap = |</a></li>
    }   
}
```

Now my question is, is this code OK, and how do i add the "subcategorytitle" at the title="###" so i dont need to make a 3. 30 = TEXT and and the same field from the DB to times like this, or is it the way to do it ?

```
lib.GetSubCat = CONTENT
lib.GetSubCat {
    wrap = <div class="p_filter"><div class="p_filter_container"><a class="p_cat_filter button" href="#" title="Under Emne" data-filter="article.portfolio"><span>Under Emne</span></a><ul class="p_filter"><li class="current"><a href="#" title="Under Emne" data-filter="article.portfolio">Under Emne</a></li>|</ul></div><div class="cl"></div></div>
    table = tx_tbpdrills_domain_model_drillsubcategory
    select {
        pidInList = 18
        where = NOT deleted AND NOT hidden      
        orderBy = subcategorytitle ASC
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 0
    renderObj {
        value = <li><a href="#" title="{field:subcategorytitle}" data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='{field:subcatshort}']">{field:subcategorytitle}</a></li>
        insertData = 1
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
......
    table = tx_tbpdrills_domain_model_drillsubcategory
    select {
        pidInList = 18
        where = NOT deleted AND NOT hidden      
        orderBy = subcategorytitle ASC
    }
    renderObj = COA_INT
    renderObj {
        wrap = <li>|</li>

        10 = TEXT
        10 {
          field = subcategorytitle
          htmlSpecialChars = 1
          wrap = <a href="#" title="|"
        }

        20 = TEXT
        20 {
          field = subcatshort
          htmlSpecialChars = 1
          noTrimWrap = | data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='|']">|
        }

        30 = TEXT
        30 {
          field = subcategorytitle
          htmlSpecialChars = 1 
          wrap = |</a>
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: thx, can see its easier the B way..
What does "insertData = 1" do ?

Comment: Quotation: "The content is parsed for pairs of curly braces. The content of the curly braces is of the type `getText` and is substituted with the result of `getText`." For more information see the **[documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-insertdata)**.

Comment: Okay.. thx, and my 3. edit ex. code is ok ? or do i need some changes/fix for is so it will work the best way !

Comment: Code updated. This uses `htmlSpecialChars` without breaking the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The second example you gave is perfectly fine, but you might get a problem with a missing space between the `title` and the `data-filter` attributes in your output. Look into the stdWrap property [noTrimWrap](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-notrimwrap) to solve that.

Another problem with you code is that you miss escaping the data from the database, which also makes it potentially vulnerable against XSS attacks. You can solve that using the stdWrap-property [htmlSpecialChars](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-htmlspecialchars).

Comment: I don't think there is any need to use `htmlSpecialChars` unless... a) You don't trust the editors who populate the database. b) The content in the databse comes from the site visitors and has been saved in the database without any sanitation.

Comment: I think it is important anyway - think of a subcategoryTitle that contains a quote. It may happen even if the editor is trustworthy.

Comment: Okay Jost and Cascaval, thx alot u have saved my day and i have a better understanding of TYPO3 "get data" and thx that U just not is looking on the question, but also make it a bit better so the "security" is better.

Comment: Well, I'll have to change the code in my answer. It then cannot be as simple as the current code.

Comment: @Jost: I saw your suggested edit to my answer, adding `htmlSpecialChars` to the aprt `30`. I actually left out `htmlSpecialChars` in that part because it doesn't render inside the tag's atttribute. On the other hand, it wouldn't do any harm either. Is there any strong benefit though?

Comment: @cascaval Yes, first there is the security issue, as before. Also, it makes it possible to have HTML special characters there, without rendering the markup invalid - a subcategorytitle like "foos & bars" would produce validation errors without htmlSpecialChars.

Comment: @jost: I don't think there are any security issues but you are right about the validity issues. I'll add your suggestion to my answer.